# Dimension of $\Bbb{R^{\infty}}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Prove $\dim(\Bbb{R^{\infty}})$=$\infty$.  Suppose $\Bbb{R^{\infty}}$ has finite dimension, a number $n\in\Bbb{N}$. Define the generic basis vector $e_i$ in the usual fashion. Then the set containing $n+1$ such vectors is independent ( by induction I guess ). But why would $\Bbb{R^{\infty}}$ contain $n+1$ such vectors?

Comment: The sequences\begin{align*}e_1 &= (1, 0, 0, 0, \ldots) \\ e_2 &= (0, 1, 0, 0, \ldots) \\ e_3 &= (0, 0, 1, 0, \ldots) \\ &\vdots\end{align*}are all points in $\Bbb{R}^\infty$. There are infinitely many of them, so there are at least $n + 1$ of them.

Comment: What's $\Bbb R^\infty$?

Comment: @TheoBendit Why do such sequences exists in $\Bbb{R^{\infty}}$?

Comment: @user140878 Because they are infinite sequences, the entries of which are all real numbers. That's what I understand to be the definition of $\Bbb{R}^\infty$ (better known as $\Bbb{R}^\Bbb{N}$): the set of real sequences. If $\Bbb{R}^\infty$ means something different to you, you'll need to define it for us.

Comment: @Gae, so you don't know what $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: @RanjitKumarSarkar What if I didn't?

Comment: @Gae. S. I am just asking.

Comment: @RanjitKumarSarkar I have a better idea: if you know what user140878's answer to my first question is, provide me with that answer. Otherwise, don't ask me a different question.

Comment: I would say it is the infinite cartesian product of $\Bbb{R}$ with itself.

Comment: @user140878 And if I were to agree with you on that matter, what would I be agreeing on?

Comment: @Gae. S., Usually people denote $\mathbb{R}^n$ as the set of all vectors with $n$ real components and the vector lies in an $n$ dimensional space. So $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ should be the set of all vectors with infinitely many real components which lies in $\infty$ dimensional space.

Answer (score 5):

$X:=\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ contains the infinite vectors (or sequences, to be more precise) $e_i$, whose member $j$ is $(e_i)_j=\delta_{ij}$.

Those vectors are linearly independent, by definition. Indeed, just take a finite linear combination of them, suppose it is the $0$ vector in $X$, and reason component-wise to deduce the coefficients of the linear combination must be all $0$.

Hence $X$ cannot have finite dimension, because we found an infinite set of independent vectors inside him.

---

Addendum.

$\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ is technically the set of all functions $x: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. These functions are in turn, by definition, the real sequences, and we just denote $x(n)$ by $x_n$ to make this connection more explicit.

Then, a sequence $x$ can be represented as an "infinite vector" $x"="(x_1,x_2,...)$.